# referencing two objects in python how to convert array.x to self.array.self.x?

Tags: python, object, traits, chaco

I have and array which is made up of a bunch of variables I can call.

So normally I would call x using array.x after I import it. Now I've set them up as two objects which can be set by the user in a traits GUI. How would I extract the same information using 'self'?

```
self.array.self.variable
```

I just get attribute array has no variable 'self' because it is trying to refer to self.array.self instead of self.array.(self.variable).

Fixing this will enable me to do this using Chaco:

```
plotdata = ArrayPlotData(x = self.array.self.variable, y = self.array.self.variable)
plot = Plot(plotdata)
self.renderer = plot.plot(("x", "y"), type="scatter", color="red")[0]
self.plot = plot
```

edit: I need what normally be read as array.data['variable']. To be something like self.array.data['self.variable'].

Answer (score 1):

If `self.variable` is a string holding the name of an attribute, use `getattr`:

```
getattr(self.array, self.variable)
```

Comment: OK but it needs pull it out structured as array.data['x']. Sorry for not highlighting this before.

Comment: i.e. str(self.array) + '.data[' + str(self.variable) + ']' but how to put that back into the plotdata command?

Comment: getattr(self.array, data[self.x]) doesn't work either obviously

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you mean here (at least to me). But basically, the `self` is just the conventional name for the instance within a class method. It has local scope, so you don't reference it that way from outside it. It *is* the instance, from outside you should be able to do simply `self.array.variable`.

However, it seems you want index style access? You can do that by defining the `__getitem__` special method. Then you can do `myobj["x"]`.

Comment: data is created when a button is pushed in my GUI, hence why it is called self.data. I also have an option to select the variable, hence why that is self.variable. I just need a way to construct something like:  str(self.array) + '.data[' + str(self.variable) + ']' but that string to be read by the plotdata command.